# How to detect which Sprite got clicked on

Tags: javascript, onclick, pixi.js

Im trying to figure out how to know which Sprite got clicked on

```
   var current_dots:Array<Sprite>= [];
   for(i in 0...4){
      var page = new Sprite(); 
      current_dots.push(page);
      page.on('pointerdown', dot_click);
      this.addChild(page);
    }
   function dot_click(){
      trace("CLICKED");
    }
```

since each sprite was declared in the for-loop im not sure how to identify which one is getting clicked

Answer (score 1):

I figured a way to do it was like this

```
  function dot_click(e:InteractionEvent){
    for( i in 0...current_dots.length){
      if(current_dots[i] == e.currentTarget) {
         trace("Clicked")
      }
      
    }
  }
```

had to pass the interactive parameter